# How to make the rules 920600 and 922110 dynamic to have custom charsets (custom regexp) in CRS 4

Tags: mod-security

There is a regexp in the rules 920600 and 922110 that (according to my opinion) accepts only 4 charsets in the Accept header. I need to make it custom, so the regexp must be modified based on my custom charsets.

I understood that in **CRS 4**, the regexp is created based on 4 files: (in the folder regex-assembly)

- 920600.ra/922110-chain1.ra
- allowed-charsets.ra
- charset-specfication.ra
- charset-specification-no-anchors.ra.

These files are used by crs-toolchain to create a regexp (based on my opinion). How should I modify them to contain my own charsets? must all files be modified for this purpose? what are these files?

also is it possible to cut 920600 and 922110 from base ruleset files and place them in a custom file? is the order of these rules important?

Comment: CRS Dev-On-Duty here. As already mentioned, this question seems to be a duplicate. We do not recommend to directly change the rules, but instead to tune them. Have a look at this CRS documentation on "False Positives": https://coreruleset.org/docs/concepts/false_positives_tuning/.

Comment: Concerning your edits, I'm thinking this is still a question for the mod_security dev team, since you want to alter how things run.

Comment: But my issue is with the rules and CRS toolchain. I want to understand that what are those 4 .ra files. when I change allowed-charsets.ra and run cat regex-assembly/920600.ra | crs-toolchain regex generate - the output contains my charsets too. but I do not know what these files are used for. each of them is for what purpose?

Comment: This is a question for the OWASP CRS team, not the ModSecurity team. As I already said, please do not edit the rules directly and have a look at the linked documentation. If you need further assistance, you can also open an issue in our GitHub repository: https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues and open a "False positive" (choose the template) report.